# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at <anonymous>:3:40

Tags: javascript

first time using these commands . i was trying to create a new element and styling it inside a website with console using this javascript code .

```js
const box = document.createElement("div");
box.id = "ExtensionBox";
document.getElementById("ExtensionBox").style.height = "600px";
document.getElementById("ExtensionBox").style.background= "red";
```

console returns this :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at :3:40

Comment: because the div is not on the page yet so you can't look it up. There is ZERO reason to look it up, you already have a reference to it `box.style.height = "600px";`

Comment: `.createElement()` does not add the created element to the DOM. `.getElementById()` only looks in the DOM. So... Why do you search the element in the DOM when it is already in `box` (which you're already using for setting the `.id`)?

Comment: with this error message, you have to wondering yourself : why `document.getElementById("ExtensionBox")` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` searches the document for an element with the matching ID.

It returns `null` if it doesn't find such an element.

In this case, that is because you have just created the element and you haven't appended it to any element in document.

You don't need to search the document for it, the value of `box` is already a reference to it. Just use `box`.

```js
const box = document.createElement("div");
box.id = "ExtensionBox";

// Here we add the element to the `<body>` (and you can see it on the page now)
document.body.appendChild(box); 

// So searching the document for it finds the element
document.getElementById("ExtensionBox").style.height = "600px";
document.getElementById("ExtensionBox").style.background= "red";

// But using `getElementById` is pointless (slow, long-winded) because:
console.log(box === document.getElementById("ExtensionBox"));
```

Answer (score -3):

Change it to this:

```
const box = document.createElement("div");
box.id = "ExtensionBox";
box.style.height = "600px";
box.style.background = "red";
```

Then, append your created element to the actual dom of the page.

Comment: Code only answers aren't good answers (and people do notice when you dramatically edit a question during the 4 minute window without edit history to change it from being completely wrong to being based off someone else's answer).

Comment: My apologies; I’m new and still learning the etiquette. I will try to make more comprehensive answers going forward.